# SQL query to count number of Woocommerce orders by a list of users

Tags: mysql, sql, woocommerce

Using a SQL query, is it possible to count the number of Woocommerce orders for each user id?

```
SELECT customer_id FROM subscriptions
WHERE status = 'cancelled' GROUP BY customer_id
```

I've generated the list above of user id's, now I need to find out how many orders each one has. How can I do that using an SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `count`:

`column_to_count` is the column you want to count(for example orders maybe...)

```
SELECT customer_id, count(column_to_count)
FROM subscriptions
WHERE status = 'cancelled' GROUP BY customer_id
```

Then you can use a `left join`

```
select sub.customer_id, count(1)
from subscriptions sub
left join wp_posts wp
on wp.id = sub.customer_id
where sub.status = 'cancelled';
```

[Here is a small demo so you can show us if somethin is different.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=cee37655039d3941fcf329465ec30db0)

Comment: Thats my list of ID's from another table, I need to run that through the wp_posts table to find all orders by each user id

Comment: Then you need to show us the structure of that wp_posts table and the connection between this two tables `subscriptions` and `wp_posts`. Connection is a field that has the same value in both tables...

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated sub-query :

```
SELECT s.customer_id, count(*) AS Total,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM subscriptions s
        WHERE wp.id = s.customer_id AND s.status = 'cancelled' 
       ) AS cancelledorders
FROM wp_posts p
GROUP BY s.customer_id;
```

Comment: This is starting to go in the right direction but you're matching the customer id to the post id. It needs to find all the completed orders by those user ids

Comment: @Rob. . .Just swipe the table name.