# Grab all cancelled customers from one table and count all their orders in another

Tags: sql

How can I run an SQL query for the following:

My first table is called **"customers"** and I want to get the **"customer_id"** if the **"status"** equals **"cancelled"**

E.g

```
Customer ID | Status
001           active
002           cancelled
003           cancelled
```

My second table is called **"order_data"** and I want to get all the records that match the **"customer_id"'s** from the first table that have the "status" "shipped".

```
Customer ID | Status
001           shipped
001           shipped
002           failed
003           shipped
```

**So I'm getting all the cancelled customers from the first table, then running those through the second table to count each order that has shipped against each ID.**

This is grabbing the emails for the customers that are cancelled:

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM customers
WHERE status = 'cancelled'
```

How can I take those customer ID's and then find all their orders that have shipped in the second table. With the desired outcome being a list of customer ids and a count of how many orders each one has made?

```
Customer ID | Orders
001           2
002           0
003           1
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result (as formatted text, no images.)

Comment: Why you include `Customer ID - 001` in sample output ?

Comment: @Rob Why haven't you update this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59859226/sql-query-to-count-number-of-woocommerce-orders-by-a-list-of-users ??? Do people with 5000+ do this ?

Comment: @YogeshSharma Thats the customer id from the first table, ran through the second table then output with the order count next to it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL query to count number of Woocommerce orders by a list of users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59859226/sql-query-to-count-number-of-woocommerce-orders-by-a-list-of-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *correlated* sub-query (before question edit) :

```
SELECT c.customer_id,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM order_data od 
        WHERE od.customer_id = c.customer_id AND od.status = 'shipped'
       ) AS Orders
FROM customers c
WHERE c.status = 'cancelled'
GROUP BY c.customer_id;
```

**EDIT :** You can also do `LEFT JOIN` :

```
SELECT c.customer_id, COUNT(DISTINCT od.customer_id) AS Orders
FROM customers c LEFT JOIN
     order_data od 
     ON od.customer_id = c.customer_id AND od.status = 'shipped'
WHERE c.status = 'cancelled'
GROUP BY c.customer_id;
```

Note : If you want all customers then remove outer `where` clause with   `c.status = 'cancelled'`.

Comment: Delete the correlated sub-query part of this answer to get a +1!

Comment: This is the combination of two answers answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59859226/sql-query-to-count-number-of-woocommerce-orders-by-a-list-of-users with one new information "shipped" and new table names...My point here is to call you too to flag this question as a duplicate. Cheers!

Comment: @VBoka Sorry I did that before posting this one

Comment: @Rob, yes, I know that and that is not ok from you! You should update that question there(first one that you opened) with more info as we asked... and not to open new question... and answer what is not correct there and give people vote up because this are all helpful answers. Vote up = it helped me. Because every answer here and there is helpful... and then you choose the correct one from the first question.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following query

```sql
select customer_id, count(*)
from order_data
where status = 'shipped'
and customer_id in (select customer_id from customers where status = 'cancelled')
group by customer_id
```